# How to write a correct MySQL statement for this question

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have been practicing MySQL and doing some online questions, and found this question that I'm not able to find the correct solution for.

The question is:

A company needs a stored procedure that will insert a new user
with an appropriate type.

Consider the following tables:
TABLE userTypes

```
     id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     type VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL
```

TABLE users

```
     id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT,
     email VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
     userTypeId INTEGER NOT NULL,
     FOREIGN KEY (userTypeId) REFERENCES userTypes (id)
```

Finish the insertUser procedure so that it inserts a user, with these requirements:
• id is auto incremented.
• email is equal to the email parameter.
• userTypeld is the id of the userTypes row whose type attribute is equal to the type parameter.

Any idea how to approach or what the answer might be?

What I have so far is this, I think it's off the mark on what is but still messing with it

```
INSERT INTO userTypes (type) VALUES (type)
INSERT INTO users (email, uyserTypeId) VALUE (email, (SELECT id FROM userType 
WHERE type = "type"
```

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: @P.Salmon From what I understood from the question, I got this so far:

INSERT INTO userTypes (type) VALUES (type)
INSERT INTO users (email, uyserTypeId) VALUE (email, (SELECT id FROM userType WHERE type = "type"

Comment: Please edit the question to include the code you have so far.

Comment: Done, sorry, I'm a bit new to stackoverflow

Comment: Don't give parameters the same names as columns.and do add the procedure code and call statement.

Comment: I don't think you need to insert anything into the usertypes table, just get the usertypeid from the usertypes table based on the label.

Comment: I thing you want to look at `LAST_INSERT_ID()` [Here is a tutorial](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-last_insert_id.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

See the answer below. I changed the procedure input variables not to be named the same way as the column names otherwise I don't think it would work.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE insertUser(
    IN type_input VARCHAR(50),
    IN email_input VARCHAR(50)
)

BEGIN
    INSERT INTO users (email, userTypeId) 
    VALUES (email_input, (SELECT id FROM userTypes WHERE type = type_input));
    
END//

DELIMITER ;
```